# carrierwave whitelist error isn't displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

in my Rails app i've got the carrierwave gem to upload stuff. Now I want a validation of fileformats

so I've added this in uploader:

```
def extension_white_list
 %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
end
```

When I try to upload a pdf it dosn't upload the pdf but no error is printed to screen. What is missing?

I think the page should go back so the user has the oportunity to select a different file ?

Thanks

UPDATE - Form View Code:

```
<%= form_for(@channel, :html => {:multipart => true, :class => "form-horizontal", :role => "form"}, :method => :post, :url => url_for(controller: 'channels', action: 'edit', id: @channel.id)) do |f| %>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <label><%= f.label :channelimage %></label>
          <%= f.file_field :channelimage, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => :image%>
          <br>
          <% if @channel.channelimage.present? %>
              <div clasS="thumbnail">
                <img src="<%= @channel.channelimage %>" alt="<%= @channel.channelname %>"/>
              </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
```

UPDATE: Controller function

```
#Speichert die geänderten Werte eines Channels
def edit
  @user = User.find_by_id session[:user_id]
  @knowledgeproviderList = @user.knowledgeprovider
  @channel = Channel.find params[:id]
  @channelList = Channel.where(knowledgeprovider_id: @knowledgeproviderList.pluck(:id))
  if request.post?
    @channel.update_attributes(channel_edit_params)
    if @channel.save
      flash[:notice] = t("flash.saved")
      redirect_to action: :index
    else
      redirect_to action: :edit, :id => @channel.id
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the view code where you're outputting errors

Comment: Probably thats the problem ... at the moment nowhere ... don't know how, in the doc isn't something mentioned how

Comment: I've added the view Code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Validation - Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-some-validation)

So essentially you're not outputting errors, so using the format from the guides you need to add:

```
<% if @channel.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2>
      <%= pluralize(@channel.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
      this channel from being saved:
    </h2>
    <ul>
      <% @channel.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks I've added the code above but nothing changed.

Comment: What have you got in the controller? Carrierwave should add them when validation is run.

Comment: Right, as you're redirecting you're losing the errors.  Change the `redirect_to_action` line to be `render :edit`  Though all that part of the code should be in an update action rather than using edit